# How get file names and sizes with the help of HTML5?

Tags: javascript

How get file names and sizes with the help of HTML5?

Comment: What files are you talking about?

Comment: The guy/girl who upvoted this must be drunk!

Comment: The only vaguely-related thing I can thing of that you might *possibly* be thinking of is reading the contents of a file upload field from JS using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). This still isn't really HTML5 though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree "HTML 5" is somewhat nebulous.  But I think you may find the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [File API: Directories and System](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) working drafts helpful.